# Запятая при сложном союзе "потому что"

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, место запятой в сложном союзе влияет на смысл предложения?

> (1) Врач сегодня не принимает, **потому что** по субботам больница
>   закрыта.
>
> (2) Врач сегодня не принимает **потому, что** по субботам больница
>   закрыта.

Спасибо!

Comment: Anonym, советую прочитать данную статью, чтобы иметь  лучшее понимание этих союзов. [ПОТОМУ ЧТО или ПОТОМУ, ЧТО](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.31)

Comment: @Серж: Спасибо! : )

Answer (score 2):

Разница есть. В первом примере упор делается на том, что врач не принимает, во втором примере говорится о причине, по которой он не принимает: т. е. больница закрыта.

> Ср. аналогичный пример из справочника Д. Э. Рознталя.

*Он не пришёл, потому что заболел* — упор в сообщении делается на самый факт неявки, причина ее не уточняется; *Он не пришёл потому, что заболел* — на первый план выдвигается указание на причину неявки.

[Раздел 10. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении.  § 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)

Answer (score 2):

1) Врач сегодня не принимает, потому что по субботам больница закрыта.

(2) Врач сегодня не принимает потому, что по субботам больница закрыта.

У этих предложений разная грамматика.

В первом случае это чисто подчинительная  связь, главное предложение не зависит от придаточного, которое можно опустить. **Основной смысл сообщения в том, что врач не принимает**, причина имеет вторичное значение.

Во втором случае расчленение союза делает связь между предложениями **взаимной**. Главное предложение теряет свою полную независимость, усиливается значимость придаточного. **Теперь не сам факт, а его причина становится центром высказывания.** Логическим ударением выделена  местоименная часть союза ПОТОМУ, указывающая на содержание придаточной части.

Comment: Примечание.Удивительная вещь! Мы пользуемся справочниками по орфографии и пунктуации для определения  смысла предложения, но ведь этот смысл должен задаваться его грамматическим  строем. Получается, что грамматику мы изучаем по справочникам правописания, в то время как само правописание зависит от грамматики. Наверное, это все равно что изучать предмет по его отражению в зеркале.

Comment: Sibylla, вы считаете, что в справочнике информация лишняя по этим союзам?

Comment: В справочниках дается информация по правописанию, которая иногда сопровождается пояснениями по семантике и грамматике, то есть они как бы вторичны по отношению к письму.  Розенталь разбирает  отдельные грамматические темы, но это не учебник общего характера. Не хватает  современного академического грамматического справочника,  подходящего для практической работы.

Comment: Ну ведь здесь вопрос не по  правописанию, а по пунктуации.

Answer (score 1):

Первый пример – абсолютно корректный и нейтральный. Второй допустим только при очень большом желании сделать упор на "потому". Но мотивировка слабоватая. В следующем примере она гораздо сильнее:

*Это произошло потому, что он вовремя не потушил костёр.*

Вещь-то какая – пожар или иная катастрофа! **Почему** он произошел? А вот **потому, что...** и т.д. А что врач не принимает по субботам... Обычное дело, не такое уж важное.

Answer (score 0):

Смысловой разницы нет, это равноправные и равнозначные пунктуационные варианты. Есть случаи, когда выбор варианта зависит от структуры или контекста, в основном перечислены тут

> Чаще не расчленяется сложный подчинительный союз, если придаточное
>   предложение предшествует главному, например: Прежде чем я остановился
>   в этом березовом леску, я со своей собакой прошел через высокую
>   осиновую рощу (Тургенев); С тех пор как я женился, я уж от тебя
>   прежней любви не вижу (А.Н. Островский); По мере того как снег в
>   котелке серел и обращался в молочно-беловатую жидкость, Павел добавлял
>   снегу из ведра (Окуджава).
>
> К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:
>
> 1)      наличие перед союзом отрицания не, например: Пастухов сошелся
>   с Цветухиным не потому, что тяготел к актерам (Федин);
>
> 2)      наличие перед союзом усилительных, ограничительных и других
>   частиц, например: Наташа в эту зиму в первый раз начала серьезно петь
>   и в особенности оттого, что Денисов восторгался ее пением (Л.
>   Толстой); Водитель как раз для того, чтобы люди схлынули, застопорил
>   машину против калитки (Фадеев); Стоит ли отказываться от трудного дела
>   только потому, что оно трудное? (Крымов);
>
> 3)      наличие перед союзом вводного слова, например: ...Все это
>   имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, может быть, оттого, что я уже не
>   увижу их... (Гоголь); В гостях у Пряхиных все чувствовали себя
>   свободно, возможно, потому, что Павла Романовна никого не старалась
>   занимать (Коптяева);
>
> 4)      включение первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд
>   однородных членов, например: Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез от
>   своего бессилия и растерянности, и от боли за оскорбленную Шурочку, и
>   оттого, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось
>   вставить ни одного слова... (Куприн).

§108. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах 
Розенталь и др., "Справочник по правописанию..." 1999 г.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

Но здесь ничего не подходит.
В этом случаем, то есть при отсутствии указанных особенностей, обычным, стилистически нейтральным считается обычное построение фразы, с неразделенным союзом. 
***Врач сегодня не принимает, потому что по субботам больница закрыта.*** 
И такой вариант стоит рекомендовать, если у автора нет ясного и четкого понимания необходимости расщепления союза.

Иное же может диктоваться только акцентной установкой. Раньше считалось, при расчленении союза акцент делается на причину, а без расчленения на результат, однако в современных изданиях ([справочник РАН под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg115.php), например) и переизданиях ("Справочник по русскому языку" Розенталя после 2000 г.) подобные указания отсутствуют.

Таким образом можно считать, что вариант с расчлелением может диктоваться исключительно субъективным авторским пониманием акцента и/или ритмического построения фразы (прием, неформально именуемый "я так это слышу").

Comment: Подобная рекомендация присутствует и в справочнике Розенталя, 2007г. Что касается Лопатина, там черным по белому написано: "Но ***союзы могут расчленяться***  — в зависимости от  ***смысла предложения, логического выделения (усиления) первой части*** союза".