# Ставится ли где-нибудь запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

**Его воспитывали дальние родственники потому что его отец был болен.**

Comment: Подобный вопрос рассматривался здесь: Запятая при сложном союзе “потому что”. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431775/Запятая-при-сложном-союзе-потому-что

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Его воспитывали дальние родственники, **потому что** его отец был болен.

Сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая ставится перед союзом ПОТОМУ ЧТО.

Составной союз в этом случае **не делится на части**, так как главное предложение по своей структуре читается как самостоятельное сообщение (при членении союза ПОТОМУ,ЧТО  подчеркивается взаимообусловленность главного и придаточного предложений).

Comment: Спасибо! А почему нельзя поставить запятую после союза "потому что"?

Comment: Сложное предложение состоит из главного и придаточного предложений, их связывает союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО. Запятая разделяет эти предложения и ставится перед союзом, который относится к придаточному и не отделяется от него запятой. Но для составных союзов есть вариант членения, когда местоименная часть союза входит в главное предложение, а союзная относится к придаточному. Существуют правила для применения этих схем.  В нашем случае это выглядело бы так: Его воспитывали дальние родственники потому,  что его отец был болен. Но это менее удачный вариант.